# grep and tail -f?

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, tail

Is it possible to do a `tail -f` (or similar) on a file, and `grep` it at the same time? I wouldn't mind other commands just looking for that kind of behavior.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Using GNU `tail` and GNU `grep`, I am able to grep a `tail -f` using the straight-forward syntax:

```
tail -f /var/log/file.log | grep search_term
```

Comment: This is a solution that works with other implementations of these two utilities, not just the GNU implementation.

Comment: tail -F (capital f) will also follow new file created (if file is cycled). -f (small f) will only follow, not trace new cycled files.

Comment: This worked for me using the Bash shell, but not using the Fish shell

Answer (score 29):

Add `--line-buffered` to `grep`, and that may reduce the delay for you.  Very useful in some cases.

```
tail -f foo | grep --line-buffered bar
```

Comment: That's useful when the output of `grep` doesn't go to a terminal (redirected to another type of file). line buffering is the default when the output goes to a terminal, so it won't make any difference there. Note that that option is GNU specific.

Comment: I believe it is in the `tail`'s output where the buffering causes delays. I use `stdbuf` utility to invoke it as `stdbuf -o0 tail -f foo | grep ....`. Same can be applied to grep e.g. if it is being piped to another program, e.g. `stdbuf -o0 tail -f foo | stdbuf -i0 -o0 grep bar | another_program`

Comment: This will also make a difference when piping `grep` to yet another `grep`, and is thus very useful!

Answer (score 11):

It will work fine; more generally, `grep` will wait when a program isn't outputting, and keep reading as the output comes in, so if you do:

```
$ (echo foo; sleep 5; echo test; sleep 5) | grep test
```

Nothing will happen for 5 seconds, then grep will output the matched "test", and then five seconds later it will exit when the piped process does

Answer (score 9):

I see all these people saying to use `tail -f`, but I do not like the limitations of that! My favorite method of searching a file while also watching for new lines (e.g., I commonly work with log files to which are appended the redirected output of processes executed periodically via cron jobs) is:

```
 tail -Fn+0 /path/to/file|grep searchterm
```

This assumes GNU tail and grep.
Supporting details from the tail manpage (GNU coreutils, mine is v8.22) [https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html] :

> ```
>  -F     same as --follow=name --retry
>  -n, --lines=K
>          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output
>          starting with the Kth.
>          If  the first character of K (the number of bytes or lines)
>          is a '+', print beginning with the Kth item from the start
>          of each file, otherwise, print the last K items in the file.
>          K may have a multiplier suffix: b 512, kB 1000, K 1024, MB
>          1000*1000, M 1024*1024, GB 1000*1000*1000, G 1024*1024*1024,
>          and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.
>
>   With --follow (-f), tail defaults to following the file descriptor,
>   which means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed, tail will
>   continue to track its end.  This default behavior is  not  desirable
>   when  you  really  want  to  track the actual name of the file, not
>   the file descriptor (e.g., log rotation).  Use --follow=name in
>   that case.  That causes tail to track the named file in a way that
>   accommodates renaming, removal and creation.
> ```

So, the tail portion of my command equates to `tail --follow --retry --lines=+0`, where the final argument directs it to start at the beginning, skipping zero lines.

Answer (score 5):

You can just [pipe the output of `tail -f` into `grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/grep-and-tail-f/3230#3230). There are also programs that combine `tail -f` functionality with filtering and coloring, in particular [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) ([examples](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.html)).

Comment: @Cookie Oh, of course. I meant “pipe tail -f into grep” or “run grep on the output of tail -f”. Weird that nobody caught this in so many years!

Answer (score 2):

```
tail -f access | awk '/ADD/{print $0}'
```

Use the above, i use it usually.

Answer (score 0):

It works. But take care that output is no longer instantaneous: it gets buffered through the pipe.

Comment: Agreed. To test this, open two windows. Run `tail -f` in one window, and `tail -f logfile | grep pattern` in the other window. Lines containing `pattern` don't always appear in both windows at the same time. I've seen lines appear 30 seconds apart on rare occasions, which was annoying.

Comment: That might have more to do with the system flipping between running one or the other instance of tail.  A better test would us `tee` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use netcat to grep the results of tail -f as new results come in quite easily.

```
sudo nc -s localhost -l -p 1337 | grep ssh


tail -f /var/log/file.log | nc 127.0.0.1 1337
```

This sets grep to listen to results for input coming from port 1337.
The second command pipes the output of tail -f to netcat and sends it out localhost 1337.
To do it locally you need to switch ttys for each of the two sets of commands, or use something like screen.